# Given a projection $M = I - \frac{ww^t}{||w||^2}$ how's the result $M_w$ is orthogonal to w

Tags: matrices, optimization, gradient-descent, projection-matrices

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07868) on weight normalization authored by Salimans & Kingma. In this paper, the gradient is split into two parts where $g$ is the norm of $w$ and $v$ is the direction of gradient, the gradient of $v$ calculated as

$$\nabla_v L = \frac{g}{\|v\|} M \nabla_wL$$

where $ M := I - \frac{ww^T}{\|w\|^2} $

> Because $\Delta v \propto \nabla_vL (\text{steepest descent/ascent})$, then $\Delta v$ is >necessarily orthogonal to weight $w$ since $M$ project it away from calculating $\nabla_v L$.

I dont quite get this sentence, why $\Delta v$ must 'necessarily' orthogonal to weight $w$?
Is projection matrix $M$ any special form?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry, it appears that the article name is included. I just updated a short one.

Comment: In some ways,  this is worse. I edited the link to link to the abstract. It's nice to give people the choice to click on a PDF that may consume bandwidth unnecessarily.

Comment: "... the gradient of $v$"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the paper to understand notation, The update rule for $v$ is,

$$
v' = v + \Delta v
$$

Since, we do vanialla gradient descent (referred as steepest descent in the paper) for optimization. Assuming the step size to be $\eta$,

$$\Delta v = -\eta*\nabla_vL= -\eta*\frac{g}{||v||} M \nabla_w L$$

$\Delta v$ is orthogonal to weight $w$ because $M$ is a projection matrix that projects onto the complement of the $w$ vector. Mathematically,

$$
w^T\Delta v=-\eta\frac{g}{||v||}w^T\left( I - \frac{ww^T}{||w||^2}\right)\nabla_wL
$$

$$
w^T\Delta v=-\eta\frac{g}{||v||}\left( w^T - \frac{||w||^2w^T}{||w||^2}\right)\nabla_wL=0
$$

Hence, $\Delta v$ is orthogonal to the original weight vector $w$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the matrix $M$ is special. To see what it does let's set $$P_w:=\frac{ww^T}{\|w\|^2}.$$
If you take any vector $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$,you have
$$P_wa=\frac{ww^T}{\|w\|^2}a=\frac{w}{\|w\|^2}w^T\cdot a,$$
where the dot denotes the scalar product. This tells you that, for every $a$, the vector $P_wa$ lives in the linear subspace generated by $w$, that is $P_w$ projects vectors into the linear subspace generated by $w$.
Now you are done because $M = I - P_w$ projects vectors into the linear subspace orthogonal to $w$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808391/orthogonal-projection-onto-orthogonal-complement) for an explanation), thus $\nabla_v L$ lives in subspace orthogonal to $w$.

Comment: According to the linked question, isn't $P_w$ needs to be orthogonal projection first? Are $P_w$ satisfy that?

Comment: Yes, indeed using the definitions (of both orthogonal and projection) you can show that $P_w$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace generated by $w$ (the orthogonal projection is unique).

Comment: Thank you, I also found a question explaining some interesting properties of "Hat Matrix" $P_w$ ([question link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208242/hat-matrix-and-leverages-in-classical-multiple-regression) ).